# How to paste a link in many lines, instead of pasting it manually every time, using notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, links, paste

I hope this is possible, but didn't manage to find it.

Image for clarification:

[image]

Comment: a simple search/replace doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: You can do it with search/replace.  And, of course, learn how to use Ctrl-V vs the mouse, so you can do highlight/Ctrl-V, highlight/Ctrl-V rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not included in functionality of NP++. You can achieve the same result by using Search/Replace as @arsane has advised. If you are interested, there is an editor that allows typing in multiple locations within the document simultaneously just as you described. It is called [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/). The front page that I have linked actually demonstrate the feature you described. Don't consider it as advertising though.